# How to fix "Blocked loading mixed active content" for css and js over https

Tags: html, css, http, https, mixed-content

When attempting to view my site over https, I keep getting a "Blocked loading mixed active content" error in my Firefox console. I am getting this error only for my css and js file.

The reason I am so confused is because the reference to the files in the page code itself is https:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.example.com/style.css">
```

But in the console, it shows it as http:

> Blocked loading mixed active content "http://www.example.com/style.css"[Learn More]

I can do a view source on the page and search for "http://" and there are no results anywhere on the page.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe your server is redirecting https to http for some reason, i.e. invalid certificate. Are you sure that all of your pages and resources are under SSL ?

Comment: If you are using Drupal you can look at [this answer](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/87895)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I think that you can try with relative protocol caller.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//www.example.com/style.css">
                    ---------^^
```

if your users visit your web in http, it loads http, and if the user visit under https it loads https.

Comment: so there is no htaccess solution to this? I never use absolute urls on anything

Comment: I think this doesn't have anything to do with htaccess

Comment: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =blabla.com
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem of the request, that only forces to access the webpage by https, but if server doesn't have an SSL certificate this is not a solution. My answer is reffered to the request of external resources, and it's the solution for the problem.

Comment: The problem of this workaround is sometime we need to use third party css and not supposed to change it. I got these: `Blocked loading mixed active content “http://jsfiddle.net/font/medium/BlackTie-Medium-webfont.woff2?v=1.0.0”`, `Blocked loading mixed active content “http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/inconsolata/v16/BjAYBlHtW3CJxDcjzrnZCI4P5ICox8Kq3LLUNMylGO4.woff2”`, `Blocked loading mixed active content “http://jsfiddle.net/font/solid/BlackTie-Solid-webfont.woff2?v=1.0.0”`. In fact the browser should handle the header.

Comment: htaccess cannot provide a workaround because the browser not loading mixed content means a request is never sent to the server, so the server never gets to respond nor process a htaccess redirect