# borderRadius not working with Image uri tag in react native

Tags: react-native

I am adding a profile picture module in my app. I use **borderRadius** to make the image in the circle. It works fine with when I take an image from the assets folder but not working with when I render an image from URL. here is code

When image render from URL:

```
<View style={styles.MainContainer}>
        <Image
          source={{ uri: 'https://reactnativecode.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/2_img.png' }}
          style={{ width: 150, height: 150, borderRadius: 150 / 2 }} />
      </View>
```

[image]

When image renders from assets Folder:

```
 <View style={styles.MainContainer}>
        <Image source={require("../../assets/img/rupee.png")}
          style={{ width: 150, height: 150, borderRadius: 150 / 2 }} />
      </View>
```

[image]

Css code:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({

  MainContainer:
  {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    margin: 5,
    paddingTop: (Platform.OS === 'ios') ? 20 : 0
  }
});
```

Comment: try `overflow: 'hidden'` on your outer component, and then add the borderRadius to that outer component also

Comment: You mean to say I added overflow and borderRadius in View ?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your styling, maybe the image is the issue? and don't use overflow and border radius on the parent component it will create pixelated fragments around the border of the image on low-resolution screens.

Answer (score 0):

After some trials, I found It was image URL problem. Image URL contains https. When I use an image URL with http instead https, It works fine and thanks guys for your effort and suggestions.

Comment: Yes, take care of mixed content, you can see more info on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32307235/how-to-fix-blocked-loading-mixed-active-content-for-css-and-js-over-https/32307382#32307382

Answer (score -1):

Try below code :

```
   import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Platform, StyleSheet, View, Image, Text } from 'react-native';


export default class App extends Component {

  render() {

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.setFontSize}> Normal Image</Text>
        <Image source={require('./images/logo.jpg')} style={styles.setBorder} />

        <Text style={styles.setFontSize}> Border Radius Image</Text>
        <Image source={require('./images/logo.jpg')} style={styles.setBorderRadius} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  setFontSize: {
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight : 'bold' 
  },
  setBorder:
  {
    width: 170,  // Setting up image width. 
    height: 170,  // Setting up image height.  
    borderWidth: 3,  // Set border width.  
    borderColor: '#F44336',  // Set border Hex Color code here.   
  },
  setBorderRadius:
  {
    width: 170,  // Setting up image width. 
    height: 170,  // Setting up image height.  
    borderWidth: 3,  // Set border width.  
    borderColor: '#F44336',  // Set border Hex Color code here. 
    borderRadius: 60,  // Set border Radius.   
  }
});
```

[image]

Comment: apply overflow: 'hidden' attribute in stylesheet

Comment: applying border-radius and overflow to the parent component will result in a pixelated borders on low-resolution screens.

Comment: apply overflow: 'hidden' attribute in stylesheet for parent component.